# Update simple products with parent configurable product price

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, price

I am trying to update all my simple products linked to a configurable product with the configurable product price.

Note: I am **not** trying to update the configurable **options** with the parent price, but the **linked products**.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: have you tried some thing?

Comment: I have tried this code:
https://gist.github.com/mystix/5277464

But even though the output indicates that the code is working, no prices are actually changed.

Comment: Use this `Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::register('isSecureArea', ` instead of `require_once('app/Mage.php'); // path to magento
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store_id); // TODO - 3
echo 'loading store id: ' . $store_id . '<br />';`

Comment: Sadly this isn't doing anything. Was some of your code cut off?